# Using CloudFront to serve private content while using signed s3 urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

Currently, I am serving private S3 objects using signed urls across the globe and I am looking to accelerate certain S3 reads with CloudFront to leverage the CF<>S3 connectivity and the caching.

Unfortunately, S3 Transfer acceleration is not an option for me because, my bucket name is not DNS complaint(long-lived bucket with '.'s in the name)

I plan on using both S3 signed urls and CF.  Only a set of users will be using CF considering the cost aspects.

Is there anyway that I can use CloudFront to serve private content while using S3 signed urls?
Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Here is a great [article](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-s3-signed-urls-with-cloudfront/) which you may find helpful.